# powershell code for comparing two xls files

Tags: excel, powershell

i'am stuck coding with below requirement.

I have two excel(xls) files(old and new users list). In each file there are 4 fields "Userid", "UserName", "Costcenter", Approving Manager" . Now, i need to check whether each Userid from New user list exists in Old user list. If so, i have to copy/replace the  values of "Costcenter" and Approving Manager" in the New User list with the values from the same columns from Old user list. If this condition fails then hightlight the entire row for the "userid" in the New User List for which there is no corresponding matching record in the Old User list and finally not last but least we have to save the New user list. There are about 2000+ userid's

below, i started of coding to get the Userid list from the New user list into an Array. will be doing the same for Old user list. From there on how do i go by modifying the new user list like i explained above?

```
$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$UserWorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("O:\UserCert\New_Users.xls")
$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$OldUsers = @()
$intRow = 2 #starting from 2 since i have to exclude the header

do {
$OldUsers = $UserWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1).Value()
$intRow++
} while ($UserWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Value() -ne $null)
```

Any help Greatly appreciated...

Comment: Instead of messing up with Excel COM interface, I'd save the files in CSV format. Processing CSV in Powershell is a breeze, look at `Import-CSV`.

Comment: You can still use the Excel COM object to save the files in CSV format, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the userIDs in each list in some type of regular order, then it should be easy to open both workbooks up at the same time, maintain 2 pointers (Row_for_old_userlist and Row_for_new_userlist) and compare the contents of the New User ID with the old one.

If they aren't in some semblance of order, then for each item in the new userlist, you'll have to scan the entire old userlist to find them and then take your action.

I'm not sure that saving in CSV is a valid approach from your requirements - you may not be able to get the data that way.

However - I *think* you're really asking how to set the value of an Excel spreadsheet cell.

If so, here's some code I use to insert a list of defects into a spreadsheet...and then set the last cell's column A to a different color.  Strangely enough, that "value2" part...it's non-negotiable.  Don't ask me why it's "value2", but it is.

```
for ($x=0; $x -lt $defects.count; $x++)
    {
    $row++
    [string] $ENGIssue = $defects[$x]
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row,1).value2 = $ENGIssue
    }
$range = $sheet.range(("A{0}" -f $row), ("B{0}" -f $row))
$range.select() | Out-Null
$range.Interior.ColorIndex=6
```